# Javascript MVC Design Feedback

Tags: javascript, mvc

I would like to share my design of mvc via js.

What do you think about it? I tried to not use any mvc framework but i want to get clear structure and a decoupled organisation.

Next step for me is evaluating something like require.js to get rid of the ordering within the index file

The code:

```
XX.namespace.ContactListController = (function() {

var _initListener = function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addContact").click(function() {
            var contactName = $("#contactName").attr('value');
            var contact = new  XX.namespace.ContactModel(contactName);
            $.publish("add#contact", contact);
        });

        $("#removeContact").click(function() {
            var contactName = $("#contactName").attr('value');
            var contact = new  XX.namespace.ContactModel(contactName);
            $.publish("remove#contact", contact);
        });
    });
};

var interface = {
    init: function() {
        _initListener();
    }
};
return interface;

})(XX.namespace.ContactListModel, XX.namespace.ContactListView);


XX.namespace.ContactListModel = (function() {

var contactList = [];

/**
* @private
*/
var _addContact = function(channel, contact) {
    contactList.push(contact);
};

var _removeContact = function(channel, contact) {
    var index = contactList.indexOf(contact);
    contactList.splice(index, 1);
};

/**
* API
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.subscribe("add#contact", _addContact);
    $.subscribe("remove#contact", _removeContact);
})
 })();

XX.namespace.ContactModel = function x(name) {
this.name = name;
};

   XX.namespace.ContactListView = (function(){

var uiComponents = {
    contactList:  "#contactList"
};

var _addContact = function(channel, contact) {
    $(uiComponents.contactList).append("<li contact_name='" + contact.name + "'>" + contact.name +"</li>");
};

var _removeContact = function(channel, contact) {
    $(uiComponents.contactList+" li[contact_name='" + contact.name+ "']").remove();
};

/**
* API
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.subscribe("add#contact", _addContact);
    $.subscribe("remove#contact", _removeContact);
})
})();


     (function() {
      XX.namespace.ContactListController.init();
 })();




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script src="js/extlib/tinyPubSub.js"></script>
<script src="js/src/util/namespace.js"></script>
<script src="js/src/model/ContactModel.js"></script>
<script src="js/src/model/ContactListModel.js"></script>
<script src="js/src/view/ContactListView.js"></script>
<script src="js/src/controller/ContactListController.js"></script>
<script src="js/src/application.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
              <h2>ContactList1</h2>
    <ul id="contactList">

    </ul>
    <h1>Chat</h1>
    <div>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="contactName"/>
            <input type="button" id="addContact" value="hinzufügen">
            <input type="button" id="removeContact" value="entfernen">
        </p>


        Message: <input id="msg"  type="text" />
        <textarea id="msgContainer"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you post the right code?

What is TC.messenger?

You pass two arguments in

```
XX.namespace.ContactListController = (function(contactListModel, view)
```

and you save them as members, but never use them.

Comment: Yeah you are right. This i forgot to remove, because i changed from calling the the model and view directly to pubsub mechanism, i changed the code. C.messenger is just the namespace i forgot to mark as XX.namespace, modified my post